# Sum of two idx equal to zero. Repeated Index

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am writing the code for a method that returns the sum of its pair of indexes that added result in Zero. I have everything pretty much figured out but, I am running into an error that I haven't been able to find and is driving me crazy! 
When passing the `array = [-1, 0, 2, -2, 1].two_sum` (my method) the returning value is `[[0, 4], [1, 1], [2, 3]]` instead of `[[0, 4], [2, 3]]` (the method sorts the arr at the end). For some reason, my method is taking idx `1` twice even though, I think, I have specified in my code that I want only to compare `idx` and `idx + 1`.

What is wrong with my code?

This is what I have so far:

```
class Array
  def two_sum
    final_arr = []
    self.each_with_index do |each, idx|
      self.each_index do |comp_idx|
        unless comp_idx + 1 == self.length || idx == comp_idx
          if (each + self[comp_idx + 1]) == 0
            final_arr << [idx, comp_idx + 1].sort
          end
        end
      end
    end
    final_arr.sort
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What confuses me a bit is the fact that the resulting arr contains the same index when what I am adding is idx + idx+1 ... :/

Answer (score 2):

This code is *very* hard to understand/maintain. Anyway, there are two issues:

1. you prevent any action on `idx == comp_idx`, while then compare `idx` and `comp_idx + 1`
2. you iterate it back and forth and hence the duplicates (`[2, 3]` and `[3, 2]` leak into the result.

Here is the corrected version:

```
class Array
  def two_sum
    final_arr = []
    self.each_with_index do |each, idx|
      self.each_index do |comp_idx|
        #                                     ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
        unless comp_idx + 1 == self.length || idx == comp_idx + 1
          if (each + self[comp_idx + 1]) == 0
            final_arr << [idx, comp_idx + 1].sort
          end
        end
      end
    end
    #             ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
    final_arr.sort.uniq
  end
end
```

---

Bonus track: more idiomatic ruby version.

```
▶ arr.each.with_index.with_object([]) do |(e1, idx1), result|
    result << 
      ([idx1].product(
         arr[idx1 + 1, arr.length]. # compare only not yet compared
         each.
         with_index(idx1 + 1).      # adjust index
         select { |e2, idx2| (e1 ^ -e2).zero? }
      ))
  end.flatten(1).map { |i1, (_, i2)| [i1, i2] }
  #⇒ [[0, 4], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: OH!! That was a mistake I couldn't -clearly- spot. How could I write a more efficient version of it? I am still a Ruby beginner. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with something simple and rubyist, you can try

```
arr = [-1, 0, 2, -2, 1]
[*0...arr.size].combination(2).to_a.each_with_object([]) do |a, final_arr| 
  final_arr << a if arr[a[0]]+arr[a[1]] == 0
end
final_arr.sort
```

Comment: `combination` is the first what comes to the mind, but it’s drastically inefficient (basically, it’ll blow up on arrays of size, say, 20.) Also, you abuse `each` with a preliminary set local variable. Use `each_with_object` instead.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yeah you're right, something like `[*0...arr.size].combination(2).to_a.each_with_object([]) {|a, out| out << a if arr[a[0]]+arr[a[1]] == 0}`.

But yeah it's still very inefficient with the complexity.

Comment: I have provided the more-or-less efficient version in my answer if you are curious.

Answer (score 0):

As the problem with your code has been identified I will only suggest a different, more efficient way of computing the desired pairs of indices.

**Code**

```
def two_sum(arr)
  hneg = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
  hpos = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
  azero = []
  arr.each_index do |i|
    n = arr[i]
    case n <=> 0
    when -1 then hneg[-n] << i
    when  1 then hpos[n] << i
    else         azero << i
    end
  end
  (hneg.keys & hpos.keys).each_with_object(azero.combination(2).to_a) { |k,a|
    hneg[k].product(hpos[k]) { |pair| a << pair } }
end
```

**Examples**

```
two_sum [3, -1, 0, 1, 4, 0, -4, 0, 1]
  #=> [[2, 5], [2, 7], [5, 7], [1, 3], [1, 8], [6, 4]]
two_sum [3, -1, 0, 1, 4, 0, -4, 0, -2, -4, 5, 4]
  #=> [[2, 5], [2, 7], [5, 7], [1, 3], [6, 4], [6, 11], [9, 4], [9, 11]]
```

If `[i,j]` is an element of the array returned, either `arr[i] == arr[j] == 0` or `arr[i] < 0` and `arr[j] == -arr[i]`. If it is desired that the pairs be written with `i < j`, simply write the following.

```
arr = [3, -1, 0, 1, 4, 0, -4, 0, -2, -4, 5, 4]
two_sum(arr).map { |pair| pair.first > pair.last ? pair.reverse : pair }
  #=> [[2, 5], [2, 7], [5, 7], [1, 3], [4, 6], [6, 11], [4, 9], [9, 11]]
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

```
arr = [3, -1, 0, 1, 4, 0, -4, 0, 1]
hneg = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
  #=> {}
hpos = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
  #=> {}
azero = []
arr.each_index do |i|
  n = arr[i]
  case n <=> 0
  when -1 then hneg[-n] << i
  when  1 then hpos[n]  << i
  else         azero    << i
  end
end
  #=> [3, -1, 0, 1, 4, 0, -4, 0, 1]
```

We have just created the following hashes and array.

```
hneg
  #=> {1=>[1], 4=>[6]}
hpos
  #=> {3=>[0], 1=>[3, 8], 4=>[4]}
azero
  #=> [2, 5, 7]
```

This tells us that `arr[1] #=> -1`, `arr[6] #=> -4`, `arr[0] #=> 3`, `arr[3] == arr[8] #=> 1`, `arr[4] #=> 4` and `arr[i] #=> 0` for `i = 2, 5, 7`. Continuing,

```
common_keys = hneg.keys & hpos.keys
  #=> [1, 4]
```

This tells that the common keys of `hneg` and `hpos` are `[1, 4]`. (We needn't be concerned about other keys.)

Now compute all pairs of indices that map to `[0, 0]`.

```
zero_matches = azero.combination(2).to_a
  #=> [[2, 5], [2, 7], [5, 7]]
```

Lastly, we obtain the desired pairs of indices as follows.

```
common_keys.each_with_object(zero_matches) { |k,a|
  hneg[k].product(hpos[k]) { |pair| a << pair } }
  #=> [[2, 5], [2, 7], [5, 7], [1, 3], [1, 8], [6, 4]]
```

Note that when the common key is `k => 1`,

```
k = 1
hneg[k].product(hpos[k])
  #=> [[1, 3], [1, 8]]
```

Had `hneg[1] #=> [1, 2]` and `hpos[1] #=> [3, 4]`, we would have obtained

```
hneg[1].product(hpos[1])
  #=> [[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]
```

See the form of the class method [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a default block, [Integer#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), [Array#each_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index), [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) and [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-product) and [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an other working solution using combination and select

```
class Array
  def two_sum
    c = (0 .. count-1).to_a.combination(2).to_a
    c.select do |i,j|
      self[i]+self[j] == 0
    end
  end
end

a = [-1, 0, 2, -2, 1]
a.two_sum
```

Comment: You don’t need (and shouldn’t have, as it creates an unneeded temporary array) the second `to_a`. Dropping that causes `Enumerable#select` (rather than `Array#select`) to be used. Also, `self[i] == -self[j]` might be clearer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland also this is an efficient copy of the answer provided by Anurag Aryan one hour earlier. At the same time I dropped there a comment explaining why `combination` should not be used here. I downvoted this.

Comment: @mudasobwa : `Benchmark.measure { (1 .. 5000).map { rand(100) - 50 }.combination(2).select { |i,j| i == -j } }` runs in an average of 1.5 sec for me. Even going with floats (`rand * 100.0 - 50.0`). I'm using using ruby 2.3.3 on macOS high sierra. Can you develop on performance issues ?

Comment: @CarySwoveland oh, indeed. Fridays suck. I should not have posted anything on SO today.